# How to make multiple networks requests in chunks and with timeouts between the chunks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm having an issue , and it's that ive an api that timesout when doing 1000 requests to it with Promise.all.
This is the current code that fails

```
  const retry = async (
    requests: API.CarFailedRequest[]
  ) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const res = await Promise.all(
      requests.map(async request => {
        try {
          await service.retryFailedRequest(request);
          return { status: true, request };
        } catch (e) {
          return { status: false, request };
        }
      })
    );

    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

The code above uses a Promise.all and no distintctions so seems logic that it fails with 1000 requests, and starts giving 403 randomly.

So i have tried multiple solutions, one of them was using Bluebird concurrency.

```
  const retry = async (
    requests: API.CarFailedRequest[]
  ) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const promises = requests.map(async request => {
      try {
        await service.retryFailedRequest(request);
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    });

    await BlueBirdPromise.map(
      promises,
      async promise => {
        try {
          await promise;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
      { concurrency: 10 }
    );

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return {
    failedRequestData: { originTypes, errorTypes, statuses },
    retryFailedRequests
  };
};
```

But this doesnt seem to change anything. I still see a massive spam in the network tab in the browser , of pending requests.

I have also tried this function to natively delay chunks of network requests

```
 const processPromisesWithDelay = async (promises: any[], delay: number, split: number) => {
    const chunks = [];
  
    // Split the array of promises into chunks
    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i += split) {
      chunks.push(promises.slice(i, i + split));
    }
  
    // Process each chunk of promises with delay
    for (const chunk of chunks) {
      await Promise.all(chunk.map((promise: () => any) => promise()));
  
      // Delay for the specified amount of time
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay * 1000));
    }
  };

  const retry = async (
    requests: API.CarFailedRequest[]
  ) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const promises = requests.map(async request => {

        await service.retryFailedRequest(request);
  
    });

  await processPromisesWithDelay(promises, 5, 5);


    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return {
    failedRequestData: { originTypes, errorTypes, statuses },
    retryFailedRequests
  };
};
```

But i still see a massive amount of requests in the network tab (1000) , that resolve one after other, with no delays between them, and the chunks dont seem to be parallel or anything

Comment: Please don't call a function a promise.  When you do `promise()` in your code, that's not executing a promise.  That is executing a function that returns a promise.  Using the terminology like you are makes your code really, really confusing for someone to read.  A promise is not a function.  It's an object that manages notifications.  You don't call or execute a promise.  You call or execute a function that can return a promise object that then handles notifications for when an asynchronous operation in that function is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's mainly due to the fact that you are AWAITING the promises in chunks, but you are starting them all at the same time.

```
const retry = async (
    requests: API.CarFailedRequest[]
  ) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    await BlueBirdPromise.map(
      requests,
      async request=> {
        try {
          await service.retryFailedRequest(request);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
      { concurrency: 10 }
    );

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return {
    failedRequestData: { originTypes, errorTypes, statuses },
    retryFailedRequests
  };
};
```

This way, the BlueBird map is actually doing the request.